# Seems like the code preview is broken for this question

Tags: support, bug

[What elements should I assert for automation of my eCommerce application?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23713/common-asserts-in-any-automation-project/23718#23718)

Code in my answer looks ok when posted or viewed but when you go into edit mode the preview doesn't show all as code, some is plain text

Probably something specific about the question but I don't see it.

View Mode:
[image]

vs.
Edit Mode preview:
[image]

Comment: I think you reported this in the wrong location. If the bug affects all Stack Exchange sites, you can report them on Meta Stack Exchange, tagging the report with the bug tag. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285740/how-can-i-report-a-bug-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug.  When you put the code block in and then adjust in typing it messes everything up.  I've found it better to just write all the code in plain text and then highlight the whole thing and hit the code block feature.

I think it is the same for all stack communities though, so I agree with Niels van Reijmersdal in that it should be generally reported instead of just SQA stack meta.

This is really annoying, I agree.